# Can a widget in combination with a timeline be used as an alternative to BGAppRefreshTaskRequest?

Tags: ios, widgetkit

If an app requests to run in the background using BGAppRefreshTaskRequest, then if the user doesn't interact with the app the OS will reduce and then eventually totally stop the app from running in the background.

However, suppose the user doesn't interact with the app because the app has a widget displaying a content window and the user just views the widget and has no need to launch the app.
So if the widget has a timeline with a refresh set every few times a day, then could the widget fetch data from a server, update its own view, and store the data in a group location so that if the user does actually launch the app, then the app already has the data available instantly for display because the widget is constantly refreshing it every day?

Comment: Very interesting question! I hope somebody knows the answer.

Comment: Are you sure that _if the user doesn't interact with the app the OS will reduce and then eventually totally stop the app from running in the background_? The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/choosing_background_strategies_for_your_app) say: _Update Your App’s Content
Your app may require short bursts of background time to perform content refresh or other work; for example, your app may fetch content from the server periodically, or regularly update its internal state._ It is not mentioned that the user has to interact with the app.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner App usage is only one of the 7 factors that determine the background refresh frequency, the entire list can be found in [WWDC2020 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020-10063/?time=174). I agree with both of you that it might get reduced over time as the app is not in the foreground, but I have seen no evidence that it "eventually totally stops" and agree with you and not the OP in this regard.

Comment: @pommy (sorry Reinhard  I don't have umlauts on my keyboard to type your name). I conduced some experiments in this area a few years ago, I set an app running on a few iPhones which could record if it had been roused by the OS in the background and then looked at the results after a few days and weeks. It did appear that if you don't interact with an app the OS eventually stops running it, or at least reduces the frequency to a very tiny infrequent trickle

Comment: @Gruntcakes Widgets seem to refresh when the user looks at them - not every time, but around 40-70 times a day. Lock-screen widgets may get even more attention. I believe widgets can be a good addition to background refresh, the combination gets more attention than either alone. BTW, you can always copy umlauts from anywhere and paste them wherever you want. I used US keyboards for a long time to also write in other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [TimelineReloadPolicy.after(Date)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/timelinereloadpolicy/after(_:))

If your widget is active, you can make it reload its timeline every few hours.

```
struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
}

func getTimeline(in context: Context,
                 completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
    
    // your code here runs every few hours

    let now = Date()
    let fewHours: TimeInterval = 6 * 3600
    completion(Timeline(entries: [SimpleEntry(date: now)],
                        policy: .after(now + fewHours)))
}
```

}

Comment: The question was **not** how to update a widget, **but** if iOS will eventually stop an `BGAppRefresh` because the user doesn't interact with the app in response to a background activity.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner I disagree. The OP already stated in their first paragraph that "the OS will reduce and then eventually totally stop the app from running in the background". While I have not run enough observations to verify this statement, I did observe that re-requesting the timeline this way does work over several days without launching the app every day. That answers the title question and its detail formulated in the second paragraph.

Comment: @pommy How many days did you observe the widget continuing to get scheduled when the app wasn't run?

Comment: @Gruntcakes A few days. I can't remember exactly which iOS release, but it was a latest release or latest beta within the last three months. I also just retested it when the app was killed by swiping it up: In such a case the app does not get background refreshes until the user opens the app (or the device reboots), but it does reload widget timelines as coded above.